# how to take print out of JSP page rendered on browser from code behind

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, printing

I want to take print out of the rendered JSP page using serverside Java code.
I am also using JSF tags in my JSP page.

Currently I am using JavaScript code, but want to get rid of using client side scripting because it won't work if user disables JavaScript in browser. I am using

```
window.print();
```

Is there any way to do without JavaScript? If yes, I also would like to set the default printer and not to display print dialog box and take print using the default printer.

Comment: Try using hidden applet, but you may still need to trigger print event in the browser using some script.

Comment: @GMR: Please don't format terms/language/framework/library names as code. They are not code! Also, you didn't address a lot of other issues in the post. I fixed your bad suggested edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There (fortunately) is no provision that an HTML page can trigger a print dialog or so.
You could provide a link to popup window with a print-friendly copy of the page. Or a link to a PDF copy of the page. With JSF both are (with due effort) possible. *(Don't ask me specifics though.)*